# ListView em ordem numerica - Android

Tags: android, listview, classificação

No meu projeto, tenho que deixar uma opção para o usuário se ele quer visualizar a lista por ordem de quilometragem ou por preço.
No meu caso, estou preenchendo está lista por um `ArrayAdpter`, através de uma classe para inflar o `ArrayAdapter`, onde será preenchido com os dados da API.

```
public class MarketListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] Values;
    private MarketList[] list;

    public MarketListArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values, MarketList[] list) {
        super(context, R.layout.search_list, values);
        this.context = context;
        Values = values;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list, parent, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtProduto = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.produto);
        TextView txtMercado = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mercado);
        TextView txtQuilometros = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.quilometros);
        TextView txtValor = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.valor);

        Bitmap instIcon = loadImgCustomerFromFile(list[position].getImage());

        if (instIcon != null) {
            Bitmap roundedImage = getRoundedCornerBitmap(instIcon);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(roundedImage);
        }
        txtProduto.setText(list[position].getProduto());
        txtMercado.setText(list[position].getMercado());
        txtQuilometros.setText(list[position].getKm());
        txtValor.setText("R$ "+list[position].getValor());

        return rowView;
    }

public class MarketList {
    String Image;
    String Produto;
    String Mercado;
    String Km;
    float Valor;

    public MarketList(String image, String produto, String mercado, String km, int valor) {
        Image = image;
        Produto = produto;
        Mercado = mercado;
        Km = km;
        Valor = valor;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }
    public void setImage(String Image) {
        this.Image = Image;
    }
    public String getProduto() {
        return Produto;
    }
    public void setProduto(String Produto) {
        this.Produto = Produto;
    }
    public String getMercado() {
        return Mercado;
    }
    public void setMercado(String Mercado) {
        this.Mercado = Mercado;
    }
    public String getKm() {
        return Km;
    }
    public void setKm(String Km) {
        this.Km = Km;
    }
    public float getValor() {
        return Valor;
    }
    public void setValor(float Valor) {
        this.Valor = Valor;
    }
}

    private void loadList() {  
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMarkets);
        String[] valuesMercados = new String[]{
               new String("Texto 1"),
               new String ("Texto 2"),
               new String ("Texto 3")
        };
        MarketList[] marketLists = new MarketList[]{
                new MarketList("_1.png", "Produto 1", "Mercado 1", "4.3 km", 3),
                new MarketList("_2.jpg", "Produto 2", "Mercado 2", "5 km", 4),
                new MarketList("_3.jpg", "Produto 2", "Mercado 2", "5 km", 4)
        };
        MarketListArrayAdapter listAdapter = new MarketListArrayAdapter(this, valuesMercados, marketLists);

        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: O caminho é a solução do Rafael mesmo, mas no caso da quilometragem, será preciso alterar o tipo da propriedade para `double` (ou algo similar), já que não vai ser possível ordenar numericamente sendo esta uma `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode ordenar a sua `MarketList` utilizando:

```
Arrays.sort(marketLists, new Comparator<MarketList>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MarketList market1, MarketList market2) {
        return market1.getKm().compareTo(market2.getKm());
    }
});
```

Depois crie o seu `MarketListArrayAdapter` passando a lista ordenada e use o `setAdapter` novamente.

Você pode também criar o método de ordenação dentro do `Adapter` e chamá-lo na sua classe. Depois disso será necessário chamar o método
`notifyDataSetChanged()` do seu `Adapter`.

Comment: Funcionou do jeito que estava querendo @Rafael, porém só uma dúvida, como faria para double?

Comment: Você pode usar: return Float.valueOf(market1.getValor()).compareTo(market2.getValor());

Comment: funcionou perfeito, isso que estava buscando !!!